# Modifying topMargin of a Relativelayout programmatically

Tags: kotlin, android-relativelayout, layoutmargins

I need to modify the top margin of a RelativeLayout programmatically

```
myScrollView.marginTop = 250
```

Unfortunately I receive the error **val cannot be reassigned**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    ...
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        tools:context=".QuizActivity">
        ...
```

Is there a different way to do it please?

Thanks in advance for the appreciated help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the layoutparams of the view first and then setMargins.

```
val param = myScrollView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
param.setMargins(left,top,right,bottom)
```

then set the params to the layout or the view.

```
myScrollView.layoutparams = param
```

Comment: Thankyou very much Yoron, you save my day !

Comment: @LastCard1440 No problem happy to help...

Comment: the last thing is to make a frame around that scrollView :-/

Comment: @LastCard1440 Do you mean like a background with stroke on the sides?

Comment: Yes I tried some things unsuccessful. A drawable frame as a xml file then called it in the layout of the scrollView. Now a frame appear on screen before I call te ScrollView. Then when the scrollView come on screen the frame is like a sandwich on top and bottom of the scrollView, not on the sides. Bigger than the scrollView itself.

Comment: @LastCard1440 can you dm me on Discord: yorondadude#1001 or Instagram: noah.mostarihi and send me a picture of the screen